# Problem with initializing an array of List<int> with Initialize method

Tags: c#, array-initialization

I want to implement a graph with an array of `List<int>`, but when I try to initialize the entries with `Array.Initialize()` with the default values (by calling a parameterless constructor of `List<int>`), it's like the method was never called and after that all entries are still `null`!

```
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // number of nodes 
List<int>[] g = new List<int>[n]; //graph
g.Initialize();
```

It's fine when I iterate over the collection and intitialize, but why is there a problem with the method `Initialize()`?

Comment: `List<T>[]` is an array though, and that's what he wrote in his code. Could you explain further what exactly you're talking about?

Comment: @Blindy Your right, I am blind, that is in fact an array of List<int>.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Array.Initialize`, ever. Read the documentation on the function, it has an entire page of warnings, including a huge red caution box.

Instead initialize your array as you would any other:

```
for(int i = 0; i < g.Count; ++i)
    g[i] = new();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your data-type to int[]=>

```
var myArray = new int[n];
```

Or If you need for any reason List you can initializing it as shown in below section=>

```
var defaultValue=65;
var myListWithDefaultValue = Enumerable.Repeat(defaultValue, n).ToList();
```